# Cypress get Function with two class names

Tags: jquery, cypress, end-to-end

I have a button on my website with two classes:

```
<button class="btn_primary btn_inventory">ADD TO CART</button>
```

I want to click this button with this code:

```
 cy.get('btn_primary btn_inventory').click();
```

Comment: Remove the space and replace it with a `.` like `'btn_primary.btn_inventory'` Dont know `Cypress` but you might also need a `.` at the start `'.btn_primary.btn_inventory'`

Answer (score 12):

You can't directly use the class name as you have used here. you need to use CSS selectors.
in your case, it should be corrected as,

```
cy.get('.btn_primary.btn_inventory').click();
```

Refer this to learn more about css selectors
[CSS Selectors W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)